# Asking several related questions

Tags: discussion, questions

I have several small-ish questions about the viability of rooting a Nook Color for use as a general purpose tablet. I am considering getting one, and these are technical questions about the root process and operation of the NC that I'd like to find answers for before I make a decision. They are not "should I buy one" questions so I think they definitely fall outside the scope of a shopping recommendation. It's more research than anything else.

Would it be best to post them in one bullet-pointed question, or break them up? They're all pretty narrow in scope, so I'm a little on the fence. I found [this related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts) on Meta SO, but I'm still not quite sure if it would make sense to have about 5 one- or two-line questions instead of one that's roughly half a page or so.

Comment: Feel free to ask the questions.  I have a rooted Nook Color and can help point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can make them distinct questions that don't really rely on each other, I'd post them separately.  If the questions are naturally follow-ups to each other and may be irrelevant/different/etc. depending on how the other questions are answered, post them together.

If your question is really "How do I root the Nook Color?" or "How can I use the Nook Color as a general-purpose tablet?" and you just have specific concerns about each, I would probably post them together.  I believe Bryan Denny has an NC that he's experimented with, and he could probably provide a good single answer.

Comment: This is sort of what I was wrestling with. My concerns aren't really "How do I root the NC?" because the guides I've found are more than adequate, I believe. It's more along the lines of "How much of the internal memory will I have access to for apps?" and "Is there a desktop recovery/flash utility for the NC if something goes wrong?" They're fairly specific, but also related for the most part.

Comment: I think those two, at least, should be separate.

Comment: I think I'm inclined to agree. I can group some of them together in a sensible way but break up others, so I'll go with that. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 4):

I think you ought to split each question up, that way it makes the process of choosing the correct answers easier.